# flex 3 animated gif for datagrid loading

Tags: apache-flex, animated

I want to display some kind of animation when my datagrid is updating. Does anyone have any good examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a gif as a loader because there is no built-in support for animated gif.
Try to use a SWF instead.

Then you could use a Canvas as a container for your DataGrid and the Loader. When your DataGrid is updating, add your loader on top of it and remove it when your data is ready.

However, if you can't use anything else than an animated gif, you can find an AS3 Gif Loader here : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95&cpage=2